# How do I save the text added to an ajax html editor, as an html document?

Tags: asp.net, html, ajax

I added an AJAX html editor to my ASP.NET web app and it is working fine.  However, when I save the contents of the editor to my sql database it just saves the html.  I need to save this as an html document.  Is there a way to programatically save the contents as a document in the database, which can then be opened using my asp.net app?  Also, is there a way to use the html editor to anchor sections of the text added in the editor?

Thank you for all your help,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most html editors only insert snippets of html, so what you can do is take the contents of the editor and add into an html document, before inserting into the database.

```
string.Concat('<html><body>', editor_contents, '</body></html>');
```

You will have to modify this to suit your specific needs, but this should get you started. To anchor text you just need to add an id to the section you would like anchored.

```
<a href="#someID">Go to section</a>
<div id="someID">Section</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for help.  I used the following:  
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Comment1"].DefaultValue = string.Concat("<html><body>", txtComments, "</body></html>");  but all I get in the database is <html><body>System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox</body></html>

Comment: I ended up using String Builder to generate my html document and then added the anchor syntax as you suggested.  Now I can simply access webpages that are sitting on the server and go to the section I need using the anchor.  Thank you so much for hinting me in the right direction :)