# How do you store HTML documents in a database?

Tags: asp.net, html, ajax

I need to create an HTML document (webpage) with anchors, and have that file saved somewhere, another program will be linking to these documents via their URL with the anchor syntax at the end so that they are directed to the correct part of the document.

What is the best way to do this? Do I programmatically generate the HTML document and insert the anchor points, then get the user to save this document on their server? How would I get the URL to the location of this document? I am using ASP.NET.

Or, do I just use an HTML text editor to save the HTML as a varchar(MAX) in the SQL database. BUT, if I do this, how can I add the anchors?AND, how can I read the HTML in a browser when it is stored as a long string in the database (I have yet to find anyone who knows the answer to that)? I have tried LITERALS and iFRAME but neither render the HTML content from the database.

I am thinking the best way is to programmartically generate the HTML document, this way I have control over entering anchor points (I don't think this is possible with the Ajax HTML editor). Then simply have the user save this document (webpage) anywhere they want on their computer/server. Then, if I have the URL, I can get this other program to go to that document, at the anchor point, by knowing the URL of its location.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I save the text added to an ajax html editor, as an html document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444999/how-do-i-save-the-text-added-to-an-ajax-html-editor-as-an-html-document)

Comment: Don't create duplicate questions. If you need to expand on what you need, then modify the original question.

Comment: read the What kind of questions should I not ask here? in the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq. this is overly broad and not a specific programming question, which is probably why no one is answering.

Comment: The database thing should work.. I have done something similar to this but I wasn't linking to another page as I was using Wizard control and just moving on to next step in same wizard..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are several different parts to answering your question, but I think I *might* be able to help (if I've misunderstood your question then I apologize).

In the past I've had to do some limited web work and a solution that always seemed to work for me was to build your entire web page, layout and all, just without the content. From there, store all the text into varChar slots in a Sql database. This works equally well for storing URLs, so that is a possible solution to your anchors problem (this is how I kept track of image URLs).

As far as "storing" the actual pages in a database, Im not sure that's possible, or desirable even if you could. Just store the pages on the server like everything else. Past that, a simple back end used to store and load data between the page and the server is all you need to get a system like that up and running.

Since you're using ASP, I'm not 100% sure how difficult sql interaction is, but in PHP it is a very easy task. In fact, I have already designed and deployed a PHP based interfacing client that I'd be happy to share with you if you need it - just shoot me a message. Hope this helps at least somewhat, I know the answer was vague, but the question is a complex one.

Comment: Wow, thank you TYLER for taking the time to answer my question and providing excellent advice. It is nice when newbies like me get a respectful answer like this instead of comments like above that dont serve the purpose of a site like this. If I need your PHP code I will definitely be in touch...thanks again :)